# save vectors of different sizes in matrix

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, vector

I would like to divide a vector in many vectors and put all of them in a matrix. I got this error "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch."

```
STEP = zeros(50,1);
STEPS = zeros(50,length(locate));
for i = 1:(length(locate)-1)
    STEP = filtered(locate(i):locate(i+1));
    STEPS(:,i) = STEP;
end
```

I take the value of "filtered" from (1:50) at the first time for example and I would like to stock it in the first row of a matrix, then for iterations 2, I take value of "filtered from(50:70) for example and I stock it in row 2 in the matrix, and this until the end of the loop..

If someone has an idea, I don't get it! Thank you!

Comment: the problem is the length of `STEP` is 50, but in iteration 2 you just give it `(50:70)`, how to deal with those missing 29 digits? and that's why the error goes.

Comment: ok thank you for answering.

Comment: the problem is that I give here an example, depends of my source file, i don't know the size of the vector at each iterations. I just know that it less than 50..

Comment: At the last step, edit to : `STEPS(1:numel(STEP),i) = STEP;`?

Comment: you can query via function `length`: `temp = filtered(locate(i):locate(i+1)); len = length(temp); STEP(1:len) = temp`.

Comment: Awesome dude!! it's working perfectly!! Thank you !! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, to make it work you can edit the loopy code at the end with -

```
STEPS(1:numel(STEP),i) = STEP;
```

Also, output array `STEPS` doesn't seem to use the last column. So, the initialization could use one less column, like so -

```
STEPS = zeros(50,length(locate)-1);
```

---

All is good with the loopy code, but in the long run with a high level language like MATLAB, you might want to look for faster codes and one way to achieve that would be vectorized codes. So, let me suggest a vectorized solution using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)'s masking capability to process such *ragged-arrays*. The implementation to cover generic elements in `locate` would look something like this -

```
% Get differentiation, which represent the interval lengths for each col
diffs = diff(locate)+1;

% Initialize output array
out = zeros(max(diffs),length(locate)-1);

% Get elements from filtered array for setting into o/p array
vals = filtered(sort([locate(1):locate(end) locate(2:end-1)]));

% Use bsxfun to create a mask that are to be set in o/p array and set thereafter
out(bsxfun(@ge,diffs,(1:max(diffs)).')) = vals;
```

Sample run for verification -

```
>> % Inputs
locate = [6,50,70,82];
filtered = randi(9,1,120);

% Get extent of output array for number of rows
N = max(diff(locate))+1;

>> % Original code with corrections
STEP = zeros(N,1);
STEPS = zeros(N,length(locate)-1);
for i = 1:(length(locate)-1)
    STEP = filtered(locate(i):locate(i+1));
    STEPS(1:numel(STEP),i) = STEP;
end

>> % Proposed code
diffs = diff(locate)+1;
out = zeros(max(diffs),length(locate)-1);
vals = filtered(sort([locate(1):locate(end) locate(2:end-1)]));
out(bsxfun(@ge,diffs,(1:max(diffs)).')) = vals;

>> max_error = max(abs(out(:)-STEPS(:)))
max_error =
     0
```

Comment: Awesome!! This works even better and I learned something, and I learned a  new way to make my code faster. Thank you !!

Comment: @YannLeMat No problem! Hope you get to use `bsxfun` at more places in  more ways and do some *goodness* with it ;)

Comment: However, this code changes a little bit my row data (I mean the order of value)... because of "sort"

Comment: That sorting is introduced because there is data overlap because of `locate(i):locate(i+1)`. I did check the codes at my end to verify outputs. Hopefully you can reproduce it too.